# How to find string inside particular string and insert

Tags: java, xml, string, char, stringbuilder

I have a method that gets XML string and in theory should insert a comment before EVERY particular tag. I wonder how to make it work

```
public static String addCommentXML(String xmlString, String tagName, String comment) 
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(xmlString);
   for(int i = 0; i < sb.toString().length(); i++)
    {
        if(sb.toString().toLowerCase().contains("<"+tagName+">"))
        {
        sb.insert(sb.toString().indexOf("<"+tagName+">", i) - 1, "<!--"+ comment+"-->"+"\n");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();                  
}
```

Output of `addCommentXML("somereallylongxml", "second", "it’s a comment")`
should be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<first>

<!--it's a comment-->

<second>some string</second>

<!--it's a comment-->

<second>some string</second>

<!--it's a comment-->

<second><![CDATA[need CDATA because of < and >]]></second>

<!--it's a comment-->

<second/>

</first>
```

But it apparently doesn't work, since i don't know how to iterate through the string correctly to add before EVERY tagName, not only first, so we get infinite loop. How can i do that?

Comment: you should do this with regular expression.

Comment: But here i need to ADD something before, not replace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proposed soliution here is a very straightforward one: splitting the input by the tagname, then joining the pieces together and inserting the comment and tagname in between.

```
public static String addCommentXML(String xmlString, String tagName, String comment)
{
    String[] parts = xmlString.split("\\Q<" + tagName + ">\\E");
    String output = parts[0];
    for (int i = 1 ; i < parts.length ; i++) {
        output += comment + "<" + tagName + ">" + parts[i];
    }
    return output;
}
```

pro: no 3rd party lib required
con: this method does not really parse the xml, therefore, sometimes it can produce erronous results (like if the tag is found inside comment...)

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done with JSOUP library. It's a perfect tool to work with HTML/XML.

https://jsoup.org/

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.10.3

**In your case** it will look like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String processedXml = addCommentXML(getDocument(), "second", "it's a comment");
    System.out.println(processedXml);
}

private static String addCommentXML(String xmlString, String tagName, String comment) {
    Document document = Jsoup.parse(xmlString);
    document.getElementsByTag(tagName).before("<!--" + comment + "-->");
    return document.toString();
}

private static String getDocument() {
    return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"no\"?>\n" +
            "<first>\n" +
            "<second>some string</second>\n" +
            "<second>some string</second>\n" +
            "<second><![CDATA[need CDATA because of < and >]]></second>\n" +
            "<second/>\n" +
            "</first>";
}
```

**Output**:

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
  <first> 
   <!--it's a comment-->
   <second>
    some string
   </second> 
   <!--it's a comment-->
   <second>
    some string
   </second> 
   <!--it's a comment-->
   <second>
    need CDATA because of &lt; and &gt;
   </second> 
   <!--it's a comment-->
   <second /> 
  </first>
 </body>
</html>
```